# How to concatenate primary key with random number in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create users but before creating i want to generate and assign random numbers to them.
For random numbers i want to generate first 4 digits random and remaining other digits primary key that is going to be assigned.
For Example: there are already 5 data in my database. i want to add one data. before adding data in database. i want to generate 4 digit random number and add primary key which is 6 in database. like 3452+6 in database.

```
$digits = 4;
$ra =  rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
   return $userid = User::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'userid'=> $ra, // here i want to concatenate random number with primary key which is going 
                              to be added
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
```

Comment: So you wants to assign a unique id for user when user gets saved into db? Is that you wants

Comment: @NipunTharuksha yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as you requested this is what I do usually

Please note I assume your table structure looks like below

```
id | userid | firstname | lastname | email | password
```

**And `userid` should be null in default**

1. After saved I retrieve the last inserted ID from db
2. Then I customize the new ID as I wanted
3. Then I saved it in new field (Updating table)

Here is the code

```
$userid = User::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'userid'=> $ra, // here i want to concatenate random number with primary key which is going 
                              to be added
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
```

Now lets fetch the last inserted id

```
 $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

Then lets make it as you wants

```
    $random_id= rand(1000,10000)

   $new_id = $id.'_'.$random_id;
```

Now update the database

```
 //Updating row with registration number
  User::where('id', $id)->update(['userid' => $new_id ]);
```

Thats all

Thanks

Comment: Too much code ! just put a mutator as I mention in my answer ! it'Il will be clean and fast !

Comment: @BKF true I just wanted to explain. How ever yes you are correct

Answer (score 3):

Get the random numbers

```
$digits = 4;
$ra =  rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
```

Suppose you have 5 users already in your database. Get the total number of users(data) from your database and increase by one.

```
$count_total_data = User::count();
$increase_primary_key = $count_total_data + 1;
```

Now get the `userid` by concatenating these two numbers

```
$userid= $ra.$set_primary_key;
```

Now save the user into your User table

```
$user = new User;        
$user->userid= $userid;
$user->firstname= Input::get('firstname');
$user->lastname= Input::get('lastname');
$user->email= Input::get('email');
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
$user->save();
```

So the total code is given below

```
    $digits = 4;
    $ra =  rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
    $count_total_data = User::count();
    $increase_primary_key = $count_total_data + 1;
    $userid= $ra.$set_primary_key;

    $user = new User;        
    $user->userid= $userid;
    $user->firstname= Input::get('firstname');
    $user->lastname= Input::get('lastname');
    $user->email= Input::get('email');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->save();
```

Comment: @AashishMagar...It's my pleasure.

Comment: Perfect well explained

Answer (score 2):

Put this function in your User model:

```
public function setUseridAttribute($value)
{
     //$nextID = \DB::table('users')->max('id') +1;
     $this->attributes['userid'] = rand(1000,9999)*10 + $this::max('id') + 1;
}
```

Comment: NB: Don't put userid in your user create function

Answer (score 1):

rand() is function in php just give the min value & max value.it will generate a random number.& get a number from User model just do this & save it

```
$max_id=User::all()->max('id')+1;
$rand=rand(1000,9999)+$max_id;
```